# C++/CLI Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, c++-cli

Is there a way to create a Dictionary of Dictionaries in C++ CLI? I was previously using a Dictionary of String,ArrayList pairs and found it useful to have my ArrayList converted to a Dictionary of String,CustomValueStruct pairs instead to make use of the key matching.

The code I had for the Dictionary of String,ArrayList pairs:

```
Dictionary<String^, ArrayList^> myDictionary = gcnew Dictionary<String^, ArrayList^>();
```

How can I convert this to use a Dictionary of Dictionaries?

The code I tried using, which doesn't compile is:

```
Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, CustomValueStruct>> myDictionary = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, CustomValueStruct>>();
```

Where `CustomValueStruct` is just a custom struct in my code, which previously lived in the ArrayList.

The result of the attempted line is:

```
error C3225: generic type argument for 'TValue' cannot be 'System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey,TValue>', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler said, you forgot a `^`:

```
auto myDictionary = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, CustomValueStruct>^>();
```

Note that you need create a `Dictionary<String^, CustomValueStruct>` when adding items to `myDictionary`:

```
myDictionary.Add("Key", gcnew Dictionary<String^, CustomValueStruct>());
```

Finally, be sure you really want `CustomValueStruct` to be a value type; you're usually better off writing

```
ref class CustomRefClass { /* ... */ };
```

which in turn requires a `^` for the nested `Dictionary`:

```
 auto myDictionary = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, CustomRefClass^>^>();
```

Comment: Of course... I tried everything BUT adding the caret to the left hand side only. Thanks.

Comment: What is the advantage of a reference class over a value struct? The struct contains a couple managed strings and an ArrayList of integers. No functions or even an initializer for now

Comment: Dan, I am working in a pre-existing codebase written in C++/CLI. Trust me, I wish it were in another language, but for now I am forced to learn.